# How can we connect from WSO2 DSS to MongoDB

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

i am using MONGODB as DataBase.
    How can we connect From wso2 DSS to mongoDB just like RDBMS.

```
Is there any driver and url , if there can you please guide me.
```

Answer (score 0):

From version 3.0.0, WSO2 Data Services Server can be extended by writing custom data sources. So any possible data source can be integrated to WSO2 DSS using standard interfaces defined by data services core.

Here is a connector for MongoDB that you could use:
https://github.com/wso2/wso2-dss-connectors/tree/master/mongodb